# How to resolve Security Exception from GServices?

Tags: android

I have an app in which I am using Google Play Service and using Google Plus Login API. My problem is that sometime the app crashes and throws exception mentioned below. How can I resolve this issue?

> Caused by java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading
>   com.google.android.gsf.gservices.GservicesProvider uri
>   content://com.google.android.gsf.gservices from pid=8304, uid=10100
>   requires com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES,
>   or grantUriPermission()

Answer (score 6):

You need to ask permission in your manifest file.

If you are getting:

```
Caused by java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.google.android.gsf.gservices.GservicesProvider uri content://com.google.android.gsf.gservices from pid=8304, uid=10100 requires com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES, or grantUriPermission()
```

You need `READ_GSERVICES` permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
```

If you are getting:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.gsf.gservices.GservicesProvider from ProcessRecord{283928d 13782:com.***/***} (pid=13782, uid=10222) requires com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES or com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.WRITE_GSERVICES
```

You need both `READ_GSERVICES` and `WRITE_GSERVICES` permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.WRITE_GSERVICES"/>
```

**Note:** these permissions are almost undocumented. I found some good insights in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/98398/195103).

Comment: In my case I also needed to add `com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.WRITE_GSERVICES` permissions.

Comment: @DavidMiguel you can edit my ans os it can help other also

Comment: Done! I added some extra info

Comment: didn't work for me still getting java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.gsf.gservices.GservicesProvider

Comment: @AmitHooda thanks for down vote also did u check this https://android.stackexchange.com/a/98398

Comment: I checked that and also downloaded min sdk and target sdk version still it wasn't working. <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" /> is working now somehow i didn't change anything. Can you please edit the ans as i can't upvote it as it says its locked.